# Why is this callback firing twice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, callback

I have a jQuery ajax script to process a form on submit.  However, I have a a couple callbacks to to add "processing..." and "done" etc during the ajax request.  However, after it's all finished the script is supposed to add the `edit button` back to the person could use the form again, but it's adding the button twice.

This is where the ajax request begins, the comments will help you follow

```
$.ajax({

    url: "../ajax/update_site_info.php?id=" + $('[name="site_id"]').val() + "&field=" + $(parent).children("input").attr("name") + "&value=" + $(parent).children("input").val(),
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){

        //alert('success');

        // On success, fade out the "Saving..."
        $(parent).children('.message').fadeOut(150, function(){

            //alert('message');

            // Remove the save button (submit button)
            $(parent).children(".jUpdateSave").remove();

            // Add "Saved!"
            $(parent).append('<span class="message">' + response + '</span>');

            // Let "Saved!" linger for a while before it fades out
            $(parent).children('.message').delay(1500).fadeOut(250, function(){

                //alert("stop");  // THIS IS WHERE THINGS HAPPEN TWICE

                // Put the edit button back
                $(parent).append('<a class="jUpdate"><img src="images/shared/icon_edit.png" width="16" height="12" alt=""></a>');

                // Remove the "Saved1" message
                $(parent).children('.message').remove();
            });
        }); 
    }
}).error(function(){

    $(".message").text("There was an error proccessing your request. [0]");
});
```

The full script is [here](http://pastebin.com/z3Gq733n).

Everything about that works, except that last callback happens twice (it will alert `stop` twice).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there multiple children under `parent` with class `message`? It's difficult to say without the HTML code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does

```
$(parent).children('.message')
```

return two elements?

Comment: Aha! I was doing `$(parent).append('<span class="message">' + response + '</span>');` before removing the old message, causing two `message`s to be on the page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `.append()` on each `.message`. I assume you have two, since you reference one here:

```
$(parent).children('.message').fadeOut(150, function(){
```

and append one here:

```
$(parent).append('<span class="message">' + response + '</span>');
```

The button will be re-created for each element with the `.message` class.

To fix the problem, avoid creating multiple child elements with class `.message`, or target your `delay()/fadeOut()` statement to run only once.

Answer (score 0):

Before the ajax response for multiple request comes I think there are more than 1 `.message` spans on the page. Just to fix that try this code.

```
// On success, fade out the "Saving..."
        $(parent).children('.message').fadeOut(150, function(){

            //alert('message');

            // Remove the save button (submit button)
            $(parent).children(".jUpdateSave").remove();

            // Add "Saved!"
            $(parent).append('<span class="message">' + response + '</span>');

            // Let "Saved!" linger for a while before it fades out
            $(parent).children('.message:first').delay(1500).fadeOut(250, function(){

                //alert("stop");  // THIS IS WHERE THINGS HAPPEN TWICE

                // Put the edit button back
                $(parent).append('<a class="jUpdate"><img src="images/shared/icon_edit.png" width="16" height="12" alt=""></a>');

                // Remove the "Saved1" message
                $(parent).children('.message:first').remove();
            });
        });
```